# invoking iphone addressbook add contact view?

Tags: iphone, addressbook

In my App, I need to invoke the native add contact view. Is it possible to do it or do I need to develop my own screen and I need to add the record for the contact database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ABNewPersonViewController](http://developer.apple.com/iPhone/library/documentation/AddressBookUI/Reference/ABNewPersonViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/ABNewPersonViewController)

Answer (score 0):

See the section of the [Address Book Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/iPhone/library/documentation/ContactData/Conceptual/AddressBookProgrammingGuideforiPhone/400-UI_Controllers/UI_Controllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007744-CH5-SW5) on "Prompting the User to Create a New Person Record".